# Apache and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

guys.

OK. Trying to deploy a rails project on apache.  Ive deleted the public/index.html file.  I cant get past the "It works!" screen.  Im guessing this is a routing issue - Ive got to give it the right document root so that it can find the homepage of the app I have created, right?  Problem is, Ive tried everything - anything outside of the public folder doesnt seem to exist.  Here is my apache sites-available file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot /home/feenix/public_html/CRRC/public    


</VirtualHost>
```

I changed the rails root to "home#index".  Ive tried that as a document root for apache and it doesnt recognise it.  Any help would be appreciated, as to where I should be looking for the correct document root - do I have to add something to the public folder in the rails project?  Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! is the Apache default. That means you aren't pointing properly at Rails yet.

You've got the DocumentRoot correct.

Do you have NameVirtualHosts *:80 setup? Also, is Passenger enabled? I'm assuming you're using it.

Comment: Yes, passenger is enabled.  How do I setup NameVirtualHosts *:80?  Do I need to go into the host file?

Cheers

Comment: Also, do I have to populate the public folder in rails with any of the HTML that Ive created in rails for the app?

Comment: Nope. nothing has to go in there. If you tossed the index.html file, you're good to go.

NameVirtualHosts goes in... uh... you'll have to excuse my morning brainfart. It's httpd.conf or apache.conf, one of those. Outside of your individual host files.

Comment: Lol.  OK, jbarket - will have a look and see what I can come up with.  So I just type NameVirtualHosts in httpd.conf and thats it?

Cheers.  :-)

Comment: OK.  Tried adding NameVirtualHosts in each of the .conf files you mentioned.  Neither worked, mate.  My httpd.conf file now looks like this (had to add the first bit to get to work at all).

    `ServerName localhost
     NameVirtualHosts`


Cheers for any other help.  :-)

Comment: OK.  I have it sorted now - think something must have gone wrong when I was installing apache (stripped it out and reinstalled it and it works now).  My thanks to jbarket.  :-)